# Get string from string date in another format

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
timestamp = "2016-07-22 19:00:01.001+00";
```

I have above string and I want get **27 May 19:00**

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
formatter.dateFromString(timestamp)
```

Comment: i need two string 27 May and 19:00 from above foramt

Comment: `07-22` is actually `22 Jul`

Comment: How can he get this , ignore May Jul.

Answer (score 2):

Use date format like this,

```
formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM HH:mm"
```

OR

In your case you can get by writing like below,

```
let timestamp = "2015-07-27 19:29:50 +0000"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
let date = formatter.dateFromString(timestamp)
formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM HH:mm"
let st = formatter.stringFromDate(date!)
print(st)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You shouldn't set the timezone, using the correct timezone date format `x` `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sssx"` will take care of it

Comment: Your timestamp is different from OP's one, so I don't see how you answer their question?